# Find a regex character class with a regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, notepad++

I need to find a regex character class (that is, everything between square brackets) with a regex. So I've come up with the following regex:

```
(?<!\\)\[(?:\^\])?(?:[^]\\]+|\\.)*\]
```

And that regex works perfectly fine when I test it in Notepad++ - both in the search window (Ctrl-F) and in the RegEx Helper plugin - but I get an error when I try to use it in PHP code.

```
$string = '[^abcd\]efgh]';

$pattern = '/
(?<!\\) \[              # an opening square bracket not preceded by a backslash
  (?:\^\])?             # circumflex and closing bracket 0 or 1 times
(?:
  [^]\\]+               # not a closing bracket, nor a backslash 1-n times
 |                      # or
   \\.                  # any escaped character (including an escaped closing bracket)
)*                      # 0-n times
\]                      # closing bracket
/x';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ]
>   for character class at offset 33 in
>   C:...\test.php on line 21

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal backslash needs to be expressed in a PHP regex by four backslashes. Therefore, try

```
$pattern = '/(?<!\\\\)\[(?:\^\])?(?:[^]\\\\]+|\\\\.)*\]/'
```

Comment: So, I need to escape a backslash as the part of a PHP string and then escape those two backslashes as the part of a regex. But I don't need to double escape a backslash when it's used to escape any other character. It's very strange but it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Placido: Yes, it *is* very strange. Well, you could explain it like this: `'\\['` is the correct representation for `\[` in a string. But `'\['` will be automatically translated into `'\\['` because that's the only meaningful construct that's possible here. But this isn't possible for an actual backslash - that's why you need to be explicit here and write \\\\.